# In ARM ASM how to check from which state interrupt is raised?

Tags: assembly, arm, asmx, interrupt, thumb

In the ARM ASM programming after raising the SWI interrupt, how can whe check that whether it's raised from ARM state or THUMB state?

```
LDR R11,=DST
LDR R12,=0X4000100 ;THIS IS FOR STORING THE ADDRESS
LDR R1,=0X4000200 ;THIS IS FOR STORING THE COUNT

SWI 0X1240 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You haven't specified which version of the ARM instruction set you're using but</strike> you'll almost certainly find it in the saved program status register (SPSR).

Specifically, you want to know the value of the [T-bit](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0234b/ch02s08s02.html).

> **T bit**
>
> The T bit reflects the operating state:
>
> - when the T bit is set, the processor is executing in Thumb state
> - when the T bit is clear, the processor executing in ARM state.
>
> The operating state is reflected by the CPTBIT external signal.

Just as an aside, you generally do not need to worry about whether the interrupt came from thumb code or ARM code if you're trying to return from an interrupt. There are special return-from-interrupt instructions that are supposed to handle this for you.

On the last ARM platform I worked on, you could simply do `movs pc, lr` to return from an interrupt while also restoring the previous execution state.

Comment: The only exception for which it _does_ matter what state it came from, is an undefined instruction, where the LR offset is +4 from ARM but +2 from Thumb. For anything else, the LR offset depends purely on the type of exception (and for SVC specifically, is indeed 0).